# Multiply ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If i want this code to loop (as it does) until there's nothing more to calculate but always have a static value (C1) that doesn't continue, C2, C3 and so on, without adding a value in the formula, is it possible? Check my code and my explanation.

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "=--(B1 >= C1) * --(B1 <= C2)"
```

This loop until nothing more can be calculated, so the next row look like this

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2") = "=--(B2 >= C2) * --(B2 <= C3)"
```

i want the second row to be

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2") = "=--(B2 >= C1) * --(B2 <= C2)"
```

and so on, so C1 and C2 should not be changed at all, can i do that??

Comment: You do not require the double unaries (aka double minuses or `--`) The multiplication (or any maths operation) is sufficient to convert a boolean value to a 1 or 0.

Comment: The idea is that it should convert them to 1 or 0. but the $ sign didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

To fill the range with formulas you could try either of these:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A2").Formula = "=(B$1:B$2 >= C$1) * (B$1:B$2 <= C$2)"
Sheet1.Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "= (RC[1] >= R1C[2]) * (RC[1] <= R2C[2])"
```

The first uses implicit intersection and the second R1C1 references. R1C1 references are generally preferable being easier to maintain and using a smaller range for calculation dependencies.

If you only want the values you can try instead:

```
Sheet1.[A1:A2] = Sheet1.[(B1:B2 >= C1) * (B1:B2 <= C2)]
```

Note: `Sheet1` is here used for brevity in place of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`being the default codename of the sheet.